# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

I'm getting `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;` in the following MySQL query.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path-to-file.csv' 
INTO TABLE ls_missing_products 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r' 
ROWS (ProductID, status) 
SET status = 0;
```

Following is the full error message i'm getting.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROWS (ProductID, status) SET status = 0' at line 1`

Comment: what are you trying to do here? what are your table structure and CSV inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROWS is part of IGNORE keyword in LOAD DATA either add IGNORE or remove ROWS. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html